# document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

Tags: html

Cant seem to work out how to get the below to pass W3 validation;

Not a coding expert, so any advice on why its not passing would be appreciated

I assume it has something to do with a div in a div?

```
<!--790x250-->
<div class="mosaic-block3 bar">
<a href="contact.html" target="_self" class="mosaic-overlay">
<div class="details">
<h4>Text1</h4>
<p>Text2<br/><br/></p>  
</div></a><div class="mosaic-backdrop">
<img src="images/rotate.png" alt="rotate" />                
</div></div>
<!--end 790x250-->
```

It seems to work in every browser, just not passing W3 and i have several of these on a page working as a tile system, so quite a few errors :(

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice to know which doctype you are validating against, but I guess the problem is with the `<div>` element inside the `<a>` element, which is not permitted in xhtml doctypes. So either you should change that, or maybe start using html5 doctype.

Comment: Thanks for the replyIts based on the coding from this page http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/

Comment: It's using xhtml transitonal doctype. You can switch to html5 doctype by changing the first line to <!DOCTYPE html> or you have to remove any divs from <a> elements.

Comment: Thanks for that, i have a few new issues flagged up but its dropped by 90%! thanks for that!

Comment: Also if you change the doctype you shoud remove the xmlns and xml:lang attributes from the opening html tag, so it should look like this: <html lang="en">